# JTextArea in other JFrame display realtime console output

Tags: java, swing, scheduled-tasks, jtextarea, swingutilities

I have a "ConsoleFrame" which should display my console output in real-time to a JTextArea.

I redirected the output streams:

```
private void redirectSystemStreams() {
    OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            write(b, 0, b.length);
        }
    };

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
}
```

and call the SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait method to append the new text, which **works** fine

```
private void updateTextArea(final String text) {
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                txt_console.append(text);
            }
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
    }
}
```

but it shows me in my new ConsoleFrame this error: **java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread**
and I get that because of the EDT - but why does it work and how can I adapt my code to make it work properly?

Comment: Use `invokeLater`. Don't ignore exceptions either.

Comment: invokeLater just shows me the output AFTER the calculating process has finished, i need it realtime
i ignore the exceptions only here, to save a few lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `invokeAndWait` must be called out of EDT, otherwise caused a.m. exceptions,
- carefully with `invokeAndWait`, because can freeze whole Swing GUI, locked by exceptions from `RepaintManager` (not in all cases only GUI is created, relayout, refreshed some of methods), then applications required restart,
- for `invokeAndWait` is required to test `if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {` / `if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {` on true you can to `setText("")`/`append(""`) without any side effects, output is done on EDT, but is about good practicies to wrap inside `invokeLater`
- use `SwingWorker`, there are implemented methods `process`, `publish`, `setProcess` and `done`, all mentioned methods notified `EDT by default`,
- `SwingWorker` is designated to run only once time, for repeatly (on some period) to use `Executor` for `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread` as most simple, clear and without any side issues, effects

Comment: can y give any example how y mean that part with the Executor?
I can't use the SwingWorker in the traditionell way because I have to cover all System.out.... calls in different JPanels.

Comment: is better to use SwingWorker in the case that you have good knowledge from Java Essential Classes, example [Executor & SwingWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+[swingworker]+executor), notice Executor is black hole, missing a few important methods, the same with SwingWorker, means Executor doesn't care about invoked Object, SWingWorker is possible to listening only from PropertyChangeListener

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` from any thread, and for error stream it is likely best to use it even when you are already in EDT:

```
private void updateTextArea(final String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            txt_console.append(text);
        }
    });
}
```

That particular error you get comes from outside the EDT, and then `invokeAndWait()` may be called so you get the output to your console.

Comment: if I try this then I only get the output AFTER the whole calculating process has finished, but I want a realtime output

Comment: Are you doing the calculation in the EDT? Don't do that, use SwingWorkers for doing heavy tasks so that the EDT does not get blocked.

Comment: I can't, I want the ConsoleFrame to be perminant for every single System.out.println call - So i can't do the things in SwingWorker..

Comment: The console can stay there, and you can initialize it first. Using a SwingWorker does not prevent that in anyway. That's what it's meant for - doing the heavy work while the GUI keeps responsive.

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler: yes you can and should do this with a SwingWorker, and in fact that is the correct solution for this problem. The publish/process method pair would likely work well for your situation.